# Xamarin.Forms DataBinding in code for Switch Cell

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have the following object:

```
public class Notification : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _trafficNot;
    public bool TrafficNot 
    {
        get { return _trafficNot; }
        set {
                if (value.Equals(_trafficNot))
                    return;
                _trafficNot = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

            } 
    }

    private bool _newsNot;
    public bool NewsNot
    {
        get { return _newsNot; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_newsNot))
                return;
            _newsNot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]String propertyName=null)
    {
        var handler=PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

I get the data from an a object like this:
 //set up the notification object according to what is stored in the DB
        Notification notification = new Notification
        {

```
        TrafficNot = uInfo.NotificationTraffic,
        NewsNot = uInfo.NotificationNews
    };
```

and I want to bind the data to these switchells

```
    TableView tableView = new TableView
    {
        BindingContext = notification,
        Intent = TableIntent.Form,
        Root = new TableRoot
        {
            new TableSection
            {
                new SwitchCell
                {
                    Text = "News",
                    BindingContext = "NewsNot"

                },
                new SwitchCell
                {
                    Text = "Traffic",
                    BindingContext = "TrafficNot"
                },
                new SwitchCell
           }
        }
    };
```

What else do i need to do to bind it?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't bind view properties at all. Instead of assigning text to BindingContxt and Text property you should bind those Text properties, i.e.:

```
var sc = new SwitchCell();
sc.SetBinding(SwitchCell.TextProperty, new Binding("NewsNot"));
```

BindingContext is the source object while you are binding against its properties. See also [DataBinding docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't letting me name the SwitchCell within the TableSection so I thought that they couldn't be named - but thanks to your answer I worked out to declare outside the table.